# Tightvnc server : xstartup system wide

Tags: server, 20.04, scripts, tightvncserver

In our company, we are using VNC4Server and TightVNCserver.
VNC4server - support end up to ubuntu 18.04
TightVNCserver - ubuntu 20.04

VNC4server - we set the xstartup script in /usr/bin/vncserver as systemwide, when the user creates vnc session, vncserver generate xstartup script automatically.

tightvncserver we have to edit the xstartup script for each users.
is there any way to set the xstartup script working as systemwide, if it is possible how to do it?

Note: We are not using RDP